# My program doesn't show the result?it must show sum of its inside

Tags: python

I want to take a number and print sum of its digits, and if the sum is greater than 10, then sum the digits of that again (and so on)

```
Example: 621
6+2+1=9
print 9

Example:743
7+4+3=14
1+4=5
print 5
```

This is what I have so far:

```
num=int(input("what's the number?"))
def oneNum(num):
   numLen=len(str(num))
   tot=0
   if num>=10:
      for i in range(numLen):
         i=i+1
         tot=num%10+tot
         print(tot)
         num=num//10
   if tot>=10:
      num=tot
         oneNum(num)
   else:
      return(tot)
print(tot)
```

Comment: You defined a function called oneNum, however you never call the function. You have to call it to make it do the work.

Comment: Also you don't return in the recursive case.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the "digital root" of a number - take the sum of the digits, and if that number is greater than or equal to 10, keep doing it until you get small enough.

Normally I'd fix your code, but since I just happened to write a method like this yesterday I'll just paste it here:

```
def digital_root(num):
    root = sum(int(d) for d in str(num))
    while root >= 10:
        root = sum(int(d) for d in str(root))
    return root
```

The easiest way to do it, as you can see, is to convert the integer into a string and iterate through each character, turning it back into a single-digit number, and add them all up.

Here's a recursive version (though, due to function call overhead, it would actually be slightly less efficient):

```
def digital_root(num):
    root = sum(int(d) for d in str(num))
    return root if root < 10 else digital_root(root)
```